# Multiples file uploads with differents id in a table

Tags: java, jquery, html, spring, thymeleaf

Trying to adapt the code in:
http://blog.netgloo.com/2015/02/08/spring-boot-file-upload-with-ajax/

which works great with just one file input (used in several projects without problems).

My requeriment is to create a table with a file input in every row.

I add to the id for the input file a code. I will use that code later in my controller.

I create the table (ok)

```
<div class="table-responsive" th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(objects)}">
  <table id="d" class="table table-hover table-sm table-responsive ">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
    <tr>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Telephone</th>
      <th>File Upload</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="object: ${objects}">
      <td th:text="${object.code}"></td>
      <td th:text="${object.name}"></td>
      <td th:text="${object.addres}"></td>
      <td th:text="${object.telephone}"></td>
      <td>
        <form th:id="'uploadfileform-' + ${object.code}">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="custom-file">
              <input type="file" th:id="'uploadfileinput-' + ${object.code}"
                     name="uploadfile" accept="*" aria-describedby="fileHelp"
                     class="custom-file-input"/>
              <span class="custom-file-control"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I add to the **id** of form and  **input**  has assigned value.

My jquery

Part 1 (ok)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="file"]').change(function (e) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var res = id.split("-");
        // I pass the code
        uploadFile(res[1]);
    });
});
```

Part 2 (Fail)

```
function uploadFile(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/uploadFile",
        type: "POST",
        data: new FormData($("#uploadfileform" + id)[0]),
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function () {
            // Handle upload success
            $("#upload-file-message").text(
                "File succesfully uploaded");
            alert("File succesfully uploaded");
        },
        error: function () {
            // Handle upload error
            $("#upload-file-message")
                .text(
                    "File not uploaded (perhaps it's too much big)");
            alert("File not uploaded (perhaps it's too much big)");
        }
    });
}
```

I believe it fails in:

```
data : new FormData($("#uploadfileform"+id)[0]),
```

but I can't see a way to debug.

And this is part of the controller, exactly like in the blog:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile(@RequestParam("uploadfile") MultipartFile uploadfile) {
```

**UPDATE 1**

Changed data to:

```
data : new FormData($('input[type="file"]')[0]),
```

In both situations I get

```
POST http://localhost:8080/uploadFile 400 ()
```

thanks

**UPDATE 2**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //http://blog.netgloo.com/2015/02/08/spring-boot-file-upload-with-ajax/
    $('input[type="file"]').change(function (e) {

        //var file = $('input[type="file"][0]');
        var file = $('input[type="file"]')[0];

        alert("File name: " + file.fileName);
        alert("File size: " + file.fileSize);

    });
});
```

I get undefined, so I think this kind of code is not correct for this situation.

Comment: Hello, I see one possible error in this line `new FormData($("#uploadfileform"+id)[0])`: it should be `"#uploadfileform-"+id` (with an hyphen before the id)

Comment: Changed, was typo. data : new FormData($("#uploadfileform-"+id)[0]), I get the message from error function and in console: .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'uploadfile' is not present

Comment: @davisoski, can you check the generated html is as expected and also check in Chrome networks tab that the POST data is going fine or not?

Comment: @TarunLalwani added some comments

Comment: @davisoski, can you provide a git repo for debugging? This probably needs debugging

Answer (score 1):

Two issues in the code you provided. One is your sever `application.properties` is missing the `upload.file.path`. So I added

```
upload.file.path = ./
```

Next in your JavaScript code

```
            $('input[type="file"]').change(function(e) {
                //id is undefined
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

The id you assign is on the form field and not on input. So I updated below

```
<form th:id="'uploadfileform-'+${directory.code}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="custom-file"> <input type="file"
            th:name="uploadfile" accept="*" aria-describedby="fileHelp"
            class="custom-file-input"/> <span
            class="custom-file-control"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

to

```
<form th:id="'uploadfileform-'+${directory.code}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="custom-file"> <input type="file"
            th:name="uploadfile" accept="*" aria-describedby="fileHelp"
            class="custom-file-input" th:id="'uploadfileinput-'+${directory.code}"/> <span
            class="custom-file-control"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

After those two changes, it works fine

[image: Working]

Comment: Hi. My code wich is almost the same as yours, is not parsed correctly: <form th:id="uploadfileform-${directorio.codigo}">, I'll prepare a springboot project in github. Thanksss

Comment: Hi. Created a spring project in: https://github.com/elecdesa/multiple_fileupload thanks

Comment: @davisoski, can you commit the static files also? so page loads exactly as you see